# Сравнение картинок php gd

Tags: gd, php

Есть каринка - на ней цифры скажем телефон [image] я порезал картинки цифр т.е. у меня есть [0-9] в отдельных фалах. Логика у меня следующая:
беру цифру получаю ее ширину и по очереди в цикле вырезаю из большой картинки такой ширины, если есть совпадение запоминаю позицию, потом сравниваю позиции и получаю список цифр и их позиций из этого генерирую текст. Вопрос: Вот вырезал я картинку, как мне ее сравнить попиксельно? Не нашел в gd такой функции намекните пожалуйста.

Comment: https://github.com/jedisct1/libpuzzle

Comment: Большое спасибо посмотрю код, а так чтобы без лишних библиотечек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в примере действительно цифры совпадают попиксельно (восьмёрки, девятки, тройки) – проверил в шопе.

В GD есть ф-я получения цвета в точке, [imagecolorat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php). Наверное, придётся попиксельно считывать цвет у каждого пикселя в тестируемой области, и сравнивать с 10 наборами, которые для скорости можно и не из файлов читать, а держать в памяти. Как только находится отличие от проверяемой цифры - начинаем проверять следующую гипотезу.

Если ещё чуть подумать, можно найти оптимальные пиксели, однозначно маркирующие каждый свою цифру, и проверять только их.

Comment: спасибо правда есть функция я ее почему-то найти не мог.

Answer (score 1):

Если ширина и высота совпадают, то можно сравнивать хеши. Как вариант [SHA](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php)